# SPARQL CONSTRUCT to generate RDF collection from GROUP BY bindings

Tags: collections, group-by, sparql, rdf, shacl

I would like to generate an RDF collection (i.e. `rdf:first`/`rdf:rest` linked list) using a SPARQL construct query, putting all grouped bindings for a variable into one collection.

So for the data

```
@prefix ex: <https://example.com/ns#> .
ex:example1  a          ex:Example ;
             ex:name    "Example1" ;
             ex:even    false .

ex:example2  a          ex:Example ;
             ex:name    "Example2" ;
             ex:even    true .

ex:example3  a          ex:Example ;
             ex:name    "Example3" ;
             ex:even    false .

ex:example4  a          ex:Example ;
             ex:name    "Example4" ;
             ex:even    true .

ex:example5  a          ex:Example ;
             ex:name    "Example5" ;
             ex:even    false .
```

if the SELECT query

```
PREFIX ex: <https://example.com/ns#>
select (group_concat(?name) as ?names) where {
  ?a ex:even ?even;
  ex:name ?name 
} group by ?even
```

yields

```
names
Example1 Example3 Example5
Example2 Example4
```

what would a corresponding `CONSTRUCT` query look like that contains the bindings for `?names` as an rdf collection, ie something like

```
( "Example1" "Example3" "Example5" )
( "Example2" "Example4")
```

(Assuming TTL interpretation of the above)

Background: I would like to generate SHACL shapes using SHACL-AF SPARQLRules, and one thing I am struggling with is to generate `sh:in (...)` where the list is generated as an aggregate over multiple solutions of the query.

Comment: that's not possible with standard SPARQL. Some SPARQL engines like Apache Jena or RDF4J might support built-in functions

Comment: I think so too. FWIW, I managed to generate lists through SHACL-AF Javascript Rules, which I prefer to the proprietary approach because it has a chance of being portable.

Comment: @UninformedUser If you want to write that as an answer, I'll accept it, until someone either proves us both wrong or alternatively sketches a way to do it with eg. a jena magic property (ie, PropertyFunction)

Answer (score 1):

I have recently seen a solution which solves this question by generating unique IRIs for the RDF collection items.

For example, the SPARQL query would be:

```
prefix ex: <https://example.com/ns#>
prefix rdf:      <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT {
 ?evenValue   ex:names ?names .
 ?names       a         rdf:List ;
              rdf:first ?minName .
 ?currentItem a rdf:List ;
              rdf:first ?currentName ;
              rdf:rest  ?nextItem .
 ?lastItem    a rdf:List ;
              rdf:first ?maxName ;
              rdf:rest rdf:nil .
 }
where {
   ?x ex:name ?minName .
   ?x ex:even ?even .
  {
    SELECT ?even (MIN(?name) AS ?minName) (MAX(?name) AS ?maxName)
    WHERE {
      ?y ex:name ?name .
      ?y ex:even ?even .
    } group by ?even
  }
  {
     SELECT ?currentName ?even (Min(?otherName) as ?nextName)
     WHERE {
            ?x ex:name ?currentName .
            ?x ex:even ?even .

            ?y ex:name ?otherName .
            ?y ex:even ?even2 .

            Filter (STR(?otherName) > STR(?currentName) && ?even = ?even2 )
     } group by ?currentName ?even
    }
  BIND(IRI(CONCAT(STR(?x), '-li-', STR(?minName))) AS ?names)
  BIND(IRI(CONCAT(STR(?x), '-li-', STR(?currentName))) AS ?currentItem)
  BIND(IRI(CONCAT(STR(?x), '-li-', STR(?nextName))) AS ?nextItem)
  BIND(IRI(CONCAT(STR(?x), '-li-', STR(?maxName))) AS ?lastItem)
  BIND(IRI(CONCAT(STR(?x), '-',    STR(?even))) AS ?evenValue)
}
```

and the results of running the query with the question's data would be:

```
@prefix ex:  <https://example.com/ns#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

ex:example1-false  ex:names  ex:example1-li-Example1 .
ex:example2-true  ex:names  ex:example2-li-Example2 .

ex:example1-li-Example1
        rdf:type   rdf:List ;
        rdf:first  "Example1" ;
        rdf:rest   ex:example1-li-Example3 .

ex:example1-li-Example3
        rdf:type   rdf:List ;
        rdf:first  "Example3" ;
        rdf:rest   ex:example1-li-Example5 .

ex:example1-li-Example5
        rdf:type   rdf:List ;
        rdf:first  "Example5" ;
        rdf:rest   () .

ex:example2-li-Example2
        rdf:type   rdf:List ;
        rdf:first  "Example2" ;
        rdf:rest   ex:example2-li-Example4 .

ex:example2-li-Example4
        rdf:type   rdf:List ;
        rdf:first  "Example4" ;
        rdf:rest   () .
```

One issue in this solution is that it would be nicer if it generated bnodes for the items in the list, but I am not sure if it is possible as the `BNODE` function generates distinct blank nodes always.

Credits: The previous solution was shown to me by Jerven Bolleman.

Comment: I created a new question about a related point on this question, which is to generate the items in the list as blank nodes, instead of IRIs here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76620537/is-it-possible-to-convert-some-iris-to-blank-nodes-in-sparql